# How can I run parallel instances of a function that returns a Try?

Tags: scala, concurrency

**I have a function that returns a `Try`, and I want to run multiple instances of it in parallel, but I’m coming up blank on how to do that – I can only seem to run it one after the other.**

Context: this function is meant to acquire a lock so that if multiple threads/workers are running in parallel, they don’t read on each other’s toes. In the tests, I want to run five instances simultaneously, and assert that all but one of them was locked out. This was working when the function returned a Future, but I’ve done some refactoring and now it returns a Try, and the test has stopped working.

The behaviour doesn’t seem to be related to the locking code – it seems I just don’t understand concurrency!

---

I’ve been trying to use `Future.fromTry`, and execute them in parallel. For example:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

object Main extends App {
  def greet(name: String): Try[Unit] = Try {
    println(s"Hello $name!")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(s"Goodbye $name!")
    ()
  }

  Seq("alice", "bob", "carol", "dave", "eve").map { name =>
    Future.fromTry { greet(name) }
  }
}
```

I’d expect to see all the “Hello” messages, and then all the “Goodbye” messages – instead, it seems to be executing them one after the other.

```
Hello alice!
Goodbye alice!
Hello bob!
Goodbye bob!
Hello carol!
Goodbye carol!
Hello dave!
Goodbye dave!
Hello eve!
Goodbye eve!
```

I looked around, and found suggestions about tweaking the ExecutionContext and adding parallelism – thing is, this environment seems perfectly happy to run Futures in parallel.

On the same machine, with the same global ExecutionContext, if I tweak the function to return a Future, not a Try, I see the output I’d expect, and the functions appear to be running in parallel.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

object Main extends App {
  def greet(name: String): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println(s"Hello $name!")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(s"Goodbye $name!")
    ()
  }

  Seq("faythe", "grace", "heidi", "ivan", "judy").map { name =>
    greet(name)
  }

  Thread.sleep(2000)  // Let the futures finish
}
```

```
Hello faythe!
Hello ivan!
Hello grace!
Hello judy!
Hello heidi!
Goodbye ivan!
Goodbye grace!
Goodbye heidi!
Goodbye judy!
Goodbye faythe!
```

What am I doing wrong with `Future.fromTry` that means it’s waiting for the Futures to finish? How do I make it match the second example?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well that was simpler than I thought, now I feel silly.  Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Done and no worries, the confusion happens because futures are **eager**, if they would have been **lazy** _(like `IO`, `Task` or `ZIO`)_, this would have the expected results. BTW, in case you feel your question may be too simple for SO, you may try asking in the [Scala gitter channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#fromTry[T](result:scala.util.Try[T]):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) explicitly states that `fromTry` will create an *already* **completed** Future from the result, thus it first evaluates the function and then lift it inside the Future context. As such, it is completely serial.

You can first create a `List[Future[String]]` from the names, and then map the list and map the inner Futures to execute your function.
Or, since a Future already represents the possibility failure (and internally uses Try), why not simply use Future in your function *(as you said it was before)*.